# Why is $('#sortthis').sortable("serialize") just returning a string that says '[object Object]'?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get an ajax version of sortable working. I have this Javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Sortable
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortThis").sortable({
            handle: '.handle',
            update: function () {

                // get new order
                var order = $('#sortthis').sortable('serialize');

                // excecute ajax for db update

                $.post(
                    "/find/ajaxactionhere",
                    order,
                    function (data) {
                        $("#info").html(data);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this html in my asp.net mvc view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>headers</th>
            <th>headers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sortThis">
        <% foreach (var item in Model) %>
        <% { %>
            <tr id="list_<%: item.Tier %>">
                <td>
                <img class="handle" src="/sortIcon.gif" />
                </td>
                <td><%: item.data %></td>
</tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This successfully allows me to reorder the all of the table rows. My action to handle the ajax post request is like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string ajaxactionhere(FormCollection form)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(":: ");

        if (form != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
            {
                sb.Append(form[key]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("null");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

the javascript variable `order` has `$('#sortthis').sortable('serialize');` assigned to it. Whenever I display `order` it says "[object Object]". I can't figure out how to get the contents of that object as a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element's ID is `sortThis` with capital `T`.

`$('#sortthis').sortable('serialize')` will just return the empty jQuery object to indicate that it didn't find any matching elements by that selector.

Change

`var order = $('#sortthis').sortable('serialize');`

to

`var order = $('#sortThis').sortable('serialize');`

and it should work.

Comment: I am an utter-complete-total idiot. I got too used to intellisense correcting that stuff.